# Matlab Uitable Adding a logical column to existing table

Tags: matlab, user-interface, checkbox, matlab-uitable

I am using a UITABLE to display some data. After displaying the table i want to add a logical column to the end of the table. And depending on columns checked or unchecked future actions are taken. Any idea Guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example:

```
%# initial table
c1 = rand(10,3);
h = uitable('Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1], 'Data',c1);

%# add new column of check boxes
c2 = c1(:,1)>0.5;
set(h, 'Data',[num2cell(c1) num2cell(c2)], ...
    'ColumnFormat',[repmat({[]},1,size(c1,2)),'logical'], ...
    'ColumnEditable',[false(1,size(c1,2)),true])
```

[image: screenshot]

You might want to handle the [`CellEditCallback`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitableproperties.html#brgcv4s) to perform custom actions.